# How to add number of months to a specific date

Tags: java, servlets

I want to add a number of months to a specific date based on what that user selected. for instance adding 3 months to 15/05/2015. 
I tried something but its showing me the same date.

Code below:

```
Calendar aed = Calendar.getInstance();
int monthsToAdd = 0;
if (advertPostedDate.equals(1)) {
    monthsToAdd = 1;
}
if (advertPostedDate.equals(2)) {
    monthsToAdd = 2;
}
if (advertPostedDate.equals(3)) {
    monthsToAdd = 3;
}

aed.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthsToAdd);
Date advertED = aed.getTime();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String advertExpiryDate = df.format(advertED);
```

Comment: Could you show how this code is used: is it in a method call? What is the type of "advertPostedDate"?

Comment: Try to print the value of `advertPostedDate`.
Imo, it's never 1 2 or 3, so you're always adding 0 month.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, with exception that I would use an `if/else if` structure instead of just the `if` structure.  Are you sure advertPostedDate has a value of 1, 2, or 3?  Because if it doesn't then 0 is being added to months.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer advertPostedDate = 2;

    Calendar aed = Calendar.getInstance(); // 15-5-2015
    int monthsToAdd = 0;
    if (advertPostedDate.equals(1)) {
        monthsToAdd = 1;
    } else if (advertPostedDate.equals(2)) {
        monthsToAdd = 2;
    } else if (advertPostedDate.equals(3)) {
        monthsToAdd = 3;
    }

    aed.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthsToAdd);
    Date advertED = aed.getTime();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String advertExpiryDate = df.format(advertED);

    System.out.println(advertExpiryDate);
}
```

Results:

> 15-07-2015

Comment: @Emmanuel Good to hear. Kindly check my answer so your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use Joda-Time

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 5, 15, 12, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime plusPeriod = dt.plusMonths(3);
```